# Matlab error for interface script

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I'm using [ksvdbox](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~ronrubin/software.html) for my research. After installing as guided in Readme, I run ksvddemo. I throws the following error:

```
Attempt to execute SCRIPT sprow as a function:
C:\Users\thdo\Documents\MATLAB\ClassificationV2\ClassificationV2\ksvdbox\private_ccode\sprow.m

Error in ksvd>optimize_atom (line 515)
[gamma_j, data_indices] = sprow(Gamma, j);

Error in ksvd (line 449)
    [D(:,p(j)),gamma_j,data_indices,unused_sigs,replaced_atoms] = optimize_atom(data,D,p(j),Gamma,unused_sigs,replaced_atoms);

Error in ksvddemo (line 74)
[Dksvd,g,err] = ksvd(params,'verbose');
```

In ksvdbox, there is a script named "sprow.m" but there is no code inside this file, only comments. In fact, there is another file named "sprow.c" in the same folder. I tried to rename "sprow.m" but it throws another error:

```
Underfined function or variable 'sprow'
```

The interesting thing is that the code works for Matlab2014a, but the errors happen on Matlab2015b.
Could you please suggest me a solution?

Comment: It is a mex file that must be compiled using `mex sprow.c` or whatever the install instructions state. Obviously renaming a `.c` file to `.m` doesn't magically make C source code run in MATLAB.

Comment: @Suever I mean renaming "sprow.m" to "somethingelse.m"

Comment: `.mex` files take precedence over `.m` files so the `.m` file purely contains the documentation. Once you compile the mex file, it won't be an issue.

Comment: But I've compiled again with "make" command and nothing changes

Comment: Do you see a mex file in that same folder that gets created?